# Extra commas in Zapier Formatter > Utilities > line item to text

Tags: zapier

I am trying to use either the line item to text formatter or split by comma formatter in Zapier.

Normally, this works fine, but sometimes an input has a comma within the text, which leads to extra outputs (line items).

For example--

This is what I would like to happen:

**Input:** Bob Smith, Jr., Firefighter

**Output:**

1: Bob Smith, Jr.

2: Firefighter

This is what I am getting:

**Input:** Bob Smith, Jr., Firefighter

**Output:**

1: Bob Smith

2: Jr.

3: Firefighter

Answer (score 0):

This won't be possible - the splitting function has no way of knowing that `Smith, Jr.` is different from `Smith, Brown`.

I'm not sure how much control you have over your input, but it's common in this case to group strings with quotes:

`"Bob Smith, Jr.", "Firefighter"`

Then you can split out each pair of matched `"` (not with the "split" tool, but with some code) and know that you're always getting the right parts.